# If a function f is surjective, is the function $f_p$ also surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

"Assume that $f:A\rightarrow{B}$ is a function that is surjective but not necessarily injective. Is $f_p$ also surjective? Prove or provide a counterexample."

$f_p$ is a function defined as: $f_p: P(A)\rightarrow{P(B)}$, $f_p(S) = \{f(s) | s \in S\}$. $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$ and $P(B)$ is the power set of $B$.

As far as I can tell, $f_p$ is also surjective, since I can't come up with a counterexample. So I set about trying to prove surjectivity. I am trying to prove that for every element $Y\in P(B)$, there exists some element $X\in P(A)$ such that $f_p(X) = Y$. To prove that $f_p(X) = Y$, I have to prove that $f_p(X)\subset Y$ and $Y\subset f_p(X)$. I have proved that $f_p(X) = Y$, by the very definition of $X$, which is $X = \{x\in A|f(x) = y, y\in B\}.$ I am having trouble proving that $Y\subset f_p(X).$

Edit: I apologize for any ambiguity in the question. I am new to stack exchange and to sets and functions. Please bear with me.

Comment: You specified the domain and image of $f_p$ but not its definition, although it is clear that it should be $f_p(X) = f[X]$

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of "surjective", we know what the structure of the proof has to be:

- Let $Y$ be an arbitrary element of $P(B)$.
- [this is what we need to figure out]
- We see that $X$ is an element of $P(A)$ and $f_P(X) = Y$.
- Since $Y\in P(B)$ was arbitrary, this shows that $f_P$ is surjective.

So ... given some $Y\in P(B)$, any idea how to construct some $X\in P(A)$ with the property that $f_P(X)=Y$?

Comment: Thanks! That's kind of where I'm stuck.

Comment: In this situation, you should work out very small examples to help you understand the general idea. For example, let $f : \{-1,0,1\} → \{0,1\}$ be the function given by $f(x) = x^2$. Can you figure out how to construct the sets $X \in P(\{-1,0,1\})$ in this very specific case?

Comment: I should make another note: I don't think this is really where you are stuck, because what you wrote in your original post does not make sense as an approach. If $X$ and $Y$ are completely arbitrary, you cannot possibly prove that $f_P(X) \subseteq Y$, since then you would have $P(B) = \{\varnothing\}$, but $B$ need not be empty. This answer has outlined the correct approach to proving surjectivity, so you should definitely begin by trying to understand how it differs from what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ be a subset of $B$. Then, $f_p(f^{-1}(Y))=Y \cap f_p(A)=Y \cap B=Y$, and so $f^{-1}(Y)$ is the desired subset of $A$ that proves surjectivity of $f_p$.